# I want to automate wifi on and off functionalities for android native apps using selenium and appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium

How to automate wifi ON and OFF through automation code using selenium and appium.

Comment: Can you be specific about your requirement?

Comment: Requirement is need to test Android native App by turning WiFi ON and OFF.

Comment: Have you tried out any code yet?

Comment: Can you check here. https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-turn-on-of-data-wifi-in-android-device-using-appium/11474

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try but found one code as below :-

```
import io.appium.java_client.NetworkConnectionSetting;

NetworkConnectionSetting connection_wifi_off = new NetworkConnectionSetting(false, false, false);
NetworkConnectionSetting connection_wifi_on = new NetworkConnectionSetting(false, true, false);
```

Source :-

https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-turn-on-of-data-wifi-in-android-device-using-appium/11474

https://discuss.appium.io/t/why-appium-server-restart-adb-server-often/15479/4

OR

```
AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), dc);

// turn on all (data and wi-fi)
driver.setConnection(Connection.ALL);
assertEquals(Connection.ALL, driver.getConnection());

// turn off all (data and wi-fi)
driver.setConnection(Connection.NONE);
assertEquals(Connection.NONE, driver.getConnection());

// turn on airplane
driver.setConnection(Connection.AIRPLANE);
assertEquals(Connection.AIRPLANE, driver.getConnection());

// turn on data
driver.setConnection(Connection.DATA);
assertEquals(Connection.DATA, driver.getConnection());

// tunr on wi-fi
driver.setConnection(Connection.WIFI);      
assertEquals(Connection.WIFI, driver.getConnection());
```

Source :-

https://medium.com/@eliasnogueira/how-to-deal-with-network-connection-in-appium-4-0-0-2134021fac25

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Start activity, get button and click.

`appPackage = "com.android.settings"`

`appActivity = '.wifi.WifiSettings'`

`driver.start_activity(appPackage, appActivity)`
`(driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.settings:id/switch_bar')).click()`